# Swift 4: Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '() -> ()' or Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: swift, closures, swift4

Using XCode 9, Beta 3. Swift 4.

```
statsView.createButton("Button name") { [weak self] Void in
   //stuff stuff
   self?.doSomething()
}
```

I get hundreds of errors like this, how do I fix them?

Errors:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '() -> ()'

Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It seems we don't use `Void in` in Swift 4 anymore. How I fixed them:

Delete the `Void` keyword:

```
statsView.createButton("Button name") { [weak self] in
   //stuff stuff
   self?.doSomething()
}
```

You have to use `in` or the compiler with complain with

```
Expected ',' separator
```

If there is no arguments then don't use `Void in` at all.

```
statsView.createButton("Button name") { //No "Void in" in here
   print("hi")
}
```